# Can't install chrome remotely through powershell script even when no error is returned

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, installation, windows-installer, remote-access

I am trying to install google chrome on a remote server but when I run my script, no error is returned and yet the MSI does not install the software automatically. This script can work locally but not remotely.

Here is the script:

```
$msi = "MSI path"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer -ScriptBlock {param($msi) Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList "/I (MSI Path) /qn /passive"} -ArgumentList $msi
```

Any help or feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think your problem is that you're using the `$msi` as local and as remote variable. Tow options:

1. For readonly variables you use the "Using" keyword

See [about_remote_variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-6#using-local-variables) about details. If you only need to read the value from a variable you can the following:

```
$msi = "MSI path"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer -ScriptBlock { Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList "/I $Using:msi /qn /passive"}
```

Here you don't need the `ArgumentList`-parameter of `Invoke-Command`.

2. Add a _remote suffix to remote variables

This is only a style I'm using in my scripts to distinguish about local and remote variables.

```
$msi = "MSI path"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer -ScriptBlock {param($msi_remote) Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList "/I $msi_remote /qn /passive"} -ArgumentList  $msi
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @Moerwald. Thank you for your comment. I believe the script does not work due to the remote server permissions i do not know about. Am going to try other methods. Really appreciate the feedback and will take it into account in future.

Comment: @LeeHanyee: If it is a permission problem on the remote server, pls answer your own question, and mark it is resolved. Otherwise the question keeps in state unanswered, and community members will try to answer this question, tough it is already solved.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Am very new to stack overflow. Will take note. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt get my script to work as it is a permission problem on the remote server. It has since been resolved.